# how to update data using before route update in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

i'm trying to update the list of products under a categories each time i click the {{category.type}} in my browser when i'm on the category.ID routes, if i click on the category it doesn't update

this is the error i get each time i click a new category on the category.Id page

```
vue-router.esm.js?880d:1905 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'category')
    at VueComponent.beforeRouteUpdate (Category.vue?0432:103:1)
```

this is my script tag

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "Product",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      category: {},
      categories: [],
      products: [],
      catID: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://taad.herokuapp.com/api/categories/${this.$route.params.id}`,
        {}
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.category = response.data.category;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        error;
      });

    axios
      .get(`https://taad.herokuapp.com/api/products`, {})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);

        this.products = response.data.products;
        const catID = this.category._id;
        // this.products = this.products.filter(
        //  ({ category }) => catID === category._id
        // );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        error;
      });
    axios.get("https://taad.herokuapp.com/api/categories").then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.categories = res.data.categories;
    });
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    // console.log('Reusing this component.')
    this.category = this.categories.find(
      category => category.id === to.params.categoryId
    );
    // console.log('Entering User', to.params.userId)

    next();
  },
  computed: {
    currentProducts() {
      if (!this.category._id) {
        return this.products;
      }
      return this.products.filter(
        ({ category }) => category._id === this.category._id
      );
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["addProductToCart"]),
    logout() {
      localStorage.clear();
      this.$router.push("/login");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

please how do i update the list of products under the specific category.id when clicked

Comment: There is no `this.data`. If you want to get the value in `data` option, just use `this.XXX`

Comment: @BigLiao like this ` this.category = this.category(to.params.categoryId) ` i'm getting  this.category is not a function

Comment: `this.category` is the Object you defined in `data` option. It's not a method...

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want.

```js
  beforeRouteUpdate ( to, from , next ) {
    // Notice: This code depends on the data struct of categories
    this.category = this.categories.find((category) => category.id === to.params.categoryId);
    next()
  },
```

---

Remove filter logic of `this.products`. So `this.products` always stores all products.

```js
   axios
      .get(`https://taad.herokuapp.com/api/products`, {})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);

        this.products = response.data.products;
        const catID = this.category._id;
        // this.products = this.products.filter(
        //  ({ category }) => catID === category._id
        // );      
      })
```

Use a `computed` value to display the products under selected category id.

```js
computed: {
  currentProducts() {
    if (!this.category._id) {
      return this.products;
    }
    return this.products.filter(
      ({ category }) => category._id === this.category._id
    );
  }
}
```

Then replace `products` with `currentProducts` in template.

Comment: Not working still need to hard refresh before I display the product under each category.id

Comment: @xander Because my code only changed `this.category`, not `this.products`.   If You want to display new products, you should update `this.products` too.

Comment: still same thing updated my code

Comment: You can give a live demo so we can help more.